# Transforming XML nesting

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm in very far over my head with XML/XSL.

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<AllNames>
    <Tier2>
        <Binary>0</Binary>
        <Name>One</Name>
        <Tier3>
            <Tier4>
            <Key>1</Key>
            <Var2>Durp</Var2>
            </Tier4>
        </Tier3>
    </Tier2>
    <Tier2>
        <Binary>1</Binary>
        <Name>Two</Name>
        <Tier3>
            <Tier4>
            <Key>1</Key>
            <Var2>Durp</Var2>
            </Tier4>
        </Tier3>
        <Tier3>
            <Tier4>
            <Key>2</Key>
            <Var2>Durp Durp</Var2>
            </Tier4>
        </Tier3>
    </Tier2>
</Tier1>
```

And am using an XSL file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <table>
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Key</th>
      <th>Var2</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="AllNames/Tier2">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <xsl:for-each select="Tier3/Tier4">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Key"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Var2"/></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I need the primary key/first column to be "Key". Right now, an element with multiple Tier 3 nests will output horizontally, i.e. all in one row. I would like each "Key" to be on its own row with the related data:

Key  Name  Var2

1    One   Durp

1    Two   Durp

2    Two   Durp Durp

Comment: Please include the desired XML output. It's a lot easier than trying to interpret, "need the primary...".

Comment: I tried to show the desired output at the end. Without using <table>, I'm not sure how to best show it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a template for the `Tier4` element to create the rows in your table. When the `Tier4` element is the context node, you can easily address it's `Key` and `Var2` children, the `Name` can be obtained from it's parent's parent.

Inside of your main template for the table, use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to "push" the `Tier4` elements and they will match the template and generate a row for each `Tier4` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Key</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Var2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="AllNames/Tier2/Tier3/Tier4"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Tier4">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Key"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Var2"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the quick and helpful response!